# Spring boot app memory increasing linearly and crashes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am running spring boot app on CF, after few hours I can see heap being increased over the time in tool like new relic. I have assigned 2GB heap (which I think should be more than enough)...after a while it crashes and CF restarts..below is actuator metric, anything hints ? Or how should I start troubleshooting this memory leak..

```
{
"mem": 1709615,
"mem.free": 359275,
"processors": 4,
"instance.uptime": 136468747,
"uptime": 136494775,
"systemload.average": 0.14,
"heap.committed": 1566208,
"heap.init": 1572864,
"heap.used": 1206932,
"heap": 1566208,
"nonheap.committed": 146944,
"nonheap.init": 2496,
"nonheap.used": 143407,
"nonheap": 1504048,
"threads.peak": 98,
"threads.daemon": 29,
"threads.totalStarted": 289750,
"threads": 43,
"classes": 14966,
"classes.loaded": 14966,
"classes.unloaded": 0,
"gc.ps_scavenge.count": 555,
"gc.ps_scavenge.time": 8110,
"gc.ps_marksweep.count": 0,
"gc.ps_marksweep.time": 0,
```

Comment: run sonar on the project? and fix all the critical and blocker issues..

Comment: make a heap dump and check what is taking all the memory. You can use the spring boot heapdump endpoint for this, or use another tool like jvisualvm wich is included in the JDK.

Comment: `I have assigned 2GB heap` -> do you mean you set the JVM's heap size or did you set the memory limit for your app to 2G? Also, what is the output in `cf events`?  Memory limit and JVM heap are not the same.  In general you should set the memory limit and let the Java build pack configure the JVM's memory settings (including heap).  If you're fiddling with the JVM memory options directly, I would suggest removing all that and just letting the JBP take control.  It will do a pretty good job of setting the values to prevent the app exceeding your memory limit (i.e. not crash).

Comment: You might also want to take a look at these slides.  They're from a presentation I did a while back, but cover a lot of the common issues I've seen with the JBP and show how to troubleshoot them.  A variety of different app crashes are discussed.  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1GQ2qrFT3rNJ6L2PURmNfEkKdQhed_vI23Q0hopVFd0o/edit